# how to insert and save json array into sqlite ios

Tags: ios, arrays, sqlite, json

```
-(BOOL)createDB{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"oiwii.db"]];
BOOL isSuccess = YES;
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt ="create table if not exists jsonData (status text, message text,  mood_name text, description text, c1 text, c2 text c3 text, c4 text, c5 text, font_name text, font_size text, font_color text)";
        if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)!= SQLITE_OK)
        {
            isSuccess = NO;
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return  isSuccess;
    }
    else {
        isSuccess = NO;
        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    }
}
return isSuccess;
```

}

i have created a database above and i am trying to add the json object(array) into my sqlite.
my json object looks like this- 
{"moods_name":"mood2","description":"this is mood 2","c1":"D4FF38","c2":"FFA83D","c3":"FFFA9E","c4":"66FFBA","c5":"63FFE8","font_name":"Default","font_size":"10","font_color":"363636"}
and i want to fetch this array

```
-(BOOL)saveData:(NSString *)status message:(NSString *)message mood_name:(NSString *)mood_name description:(NSString *)description c1:(NSString *)c1 c2:(NSString *)c2 c3:(NSString *)c3 c4:(NSString *)c4 c5:(NSString *)c5 font_name:(NSString *)font_name font_size:(NSString *)font_size font_color:(NSString *)font_color{

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into jsonData (status,message, description, c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,font_name,font_size,font_color) values (\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",status, message, description, c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,font_name,font_size,font_color];
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    { NSLog(@"data saved");
        return YES;

    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }

}

sqlite3_reset(statement);
return NO;
```

}

update:
code to fetch data

```
-(void)fetchdata
{
arrayfetched = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Setup the database object
sqlite3 *database;

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    //SQLIte Statement
    NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from moodsdata"];

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        // Loop through the results and add them to the fetchedarray
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            // Init the Data Dictionary
            NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

            NSString *status = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

            NSString *data = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

            [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",msg] forKey:@"message"];
            [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",status] forKey:@"status"];
            [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data] forKey:@"data"];

            [arrayfetched addObject:_dataDictionary];
            NSLog(@"array fetched%@",arrayfetched);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No Data Found");
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
   sqlite3_close(database);
NSLog(@" fetched array%@",arrayfetched);
}
```

please help me.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: i don't know how to save json array into sqlite save data method. i have a different class for database

Comment: and where i call json that class is different. so how to insert that json data into sqlite

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad see my answer. Hope this will help you. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method to save into database. PREPARED STATEMENTS ARE BETTER THAN NORMAL INSERT QUERY.

```
-(BOOL) saveApiResults: (NSString *)tableName : (NSArray *)data {
    //assign false value to saveSuccess
    BOOL saveSuccess = NO;

    sqlite3 *database;
    @try {
        //get database path
        const char *dbPath = [YOUR_DB_PATH UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_open(dbPath,&database)==SQLITE_OK) {

            sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);

            NSDictionary *rowData=[data objectAtIndex:0];
            //convert the string into array
            NSArray *keyArray = [rowData allKeys];

            NSString *insertSQL=@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ";
            insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:tableName];
            insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@" VALUES("];
            for(int j=0;j<[keyArray count];j++)
            {
                insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@"?"];
                if(j<[keyArray count]-1)
                    insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@","];
            }
            insertSQL=[insertSQL stringByAppendingString:@");"];


            NSLog(@"query : %@ ",insertSQL);

            const char *sqlstatement = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            sqlite3_stmt *compiledstatement;

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlstatement , -1, &compiledstatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

                //fetch the dictionary(key,value) from the array of api result
                for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [data count]; i++) {
                    NSDictionary *rowData=[data objectAtIndex:i];

                    //get the value for ech key from api response and execute the insert statement
                    for(int j=0;j<[keyArray count];j++) {
                        NSString *val = @"";
                        NSString *value=(NSString *)[rowData objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:j]];
                        if((value != nil) && (![value isEqual:[NSNull null]]))
                            val=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value];

                        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledstatement,j+1,[val UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    }

                    if(sqlite3_step(compiledstatement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                        NSLog(@"ERROR");
                    }

                    sqlite3_clear_bindings(compiledstatement);
                    sqlite3_reset(compiledstatement);


                }

                sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
                saveSuccess = YES;
                 NSLog(@"RESULTS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Statement FAILED (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement);

        } else {
                NSLog(@"Statement FAILED (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"NSException : %@",exception.description);
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    //return data save status
    return saveSuccess;
}
```

And here parse your JSON Response and send the NSArray of NSDictionary objects to saveApiResults method.

```
-(void) saveJSONData {
    NSData* jsonData = [YOUR_JSON_RESPONSE dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *responseObj = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                 options:0
                                 error:&error];

    if(! error) {
        NSArray *responseArray = [responseObj objectForKey:@"data"];

        [self saveApiResults : YOUR_TABLE_NAME : responseArray];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error in parsing JSON");
    }
}
```

//Code to fetch your results

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getQueryResult {

    //get the database path
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    sqlite3 *DB;
    NSMutableArray *results=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    @try {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        NSMutableDictionary *dict;

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &DB) == SQLITE_OK) {

            //sql select query
            NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * from moodsdata"];

            const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

                if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    do {
                        dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                        const unsigned char *msg = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);

                        const unsigned char *status = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

                        const unsigned char *data = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);

                        [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",msg] forKey:@"message"];
                        [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",status] forKey:@"status"];
                        [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",data] forKey:@"data"];

                        //add dictionary(key,value) to the array
                        [results addObject:dict];
                    }

                    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Statement FAILED (%s)",sqlite3_errmsg(DB));
                }

            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(DB));
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Can not open DB : %s",sqlite3_errmsg(DB));
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"NSException : %@",exception.description);
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(DB);
    }

    //return the database results
    return results;
}
```

//How you use the results from getQueryResults

```
-(void) showData {
    NSMutableArray *results = [self getQueryResult];
    for (NSMutableDictionary *resultDic in results) {
        NSString *msg = [resultDic objectForKey:@"message"];
        NSString *status = [resultDic objectForKey:@"status"];
        NSString *data = [resultDic objectForKey:@"data"];

        NSLog(@"Result : %@ : %@ : %@",msg,status,data);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad Welcome buddy.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad remove if(DATABASE_DEBUG_MODE_FLAG) buddy. This is just extra user defined BOOL constant. No need of this here.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad mention not buddy. In case of any issue, feel free to ask.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad replace YOUR_TABLE_NAME with @"jsonData" and also   add the above method in your same class where you implemented saveJSONData method.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad data should be NSArray object. Please check your response which you are passing to this method.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad then please first add your dictionary to NSArray. Try NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initwithobjects:YOUR_DICTIONARY]; and pass this array to saveAPIResult method.

Comment: @Microprocessor8085- hi i want your help. I am able to save the json data in sqlite. But when i fetch the data, it gets fetched in the form of string, and i am not able to assign that data to table view. Can you please help me. i will update my question for fetched code.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad please show your code of fetch database record.

Comment: @Microprocessor8085- please tell me what i am doing wrong here. i have updated my code

Comment: @Microprocessor8085- thanks again. it really saved my day.

Comment: as you have taken the results in a string, how to assign them to table view  cell labels? Because we generally pass an array to tableview. as i want to assign the "moods_name" key values to the cell labels @Microprocessor8085

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad on viewDidLoad method, call the getQueryResult method and set the NSMutableArray result as a class property and assign the database result to it. Then in numberOfRowsInSection of TableView return self.yourArray.count; Then on cellForRowAtIndexPath of TableView method, get NSMutableDictionary *dic = [self.yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; And set the cell label text as cell.label.text = [dic objectForKey:@"status"];

Answer (score 0):

You can create one class Where all the database related work is done. Call that particular method from that class wherever you want in your project to insert, update or delete anything from database.

you can refer this link for more information and tutorial: [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/06/ios-sqlite-crud-operations-example.html)